# what values can I pass to message_flags attribute in stream_socket_service::receive

Tags: c++, boost-asio

I am trying to use `socket::receive` in boost asio to receive data over network. I want it to block until certain size of data is available. For that it seems that I will have to set `message_flag` argument to the receive function, but I cannot find the information on what value can I pass so that the receive will be blocked until certain size of data is available. All I seen that its an integer.

Can someone tell me what are valid values that can be passed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> For that it seems that I will have to
>   set message_flag argument to the
>   receive function

This is incorrect. There are overloads to the [async_read](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1doc/html/boost_asio/reference/async_read/overload1.html) or [read](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/read/overload1.html) free function. They will read as many bytes as you request based on the buffer size:

> ### Remarks
>
> This overload is equivalent to
>   calling:
>
> boost::asio::read(
>       s, buffers,
>       boost::asio::transfer_all());